# xetex command line argument

Tags: xetex

Is it possible to pass an argument to xetex in the command line? For example xetex filename.tex blahblah in which case blahblah will be used in filename.tex to do whatever it is supposed to do.

Comment: `xetex '\def\blah{whatever}\input filename'` (use any valid TeX code before `\input filename`.

Comment: Thanks @egreg.  How can I mark my post as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All TeX programs can be called from the command line as

```
<program name> '<arbitrary TeX code>'
```

or

```
<program name> "<arbitrary TeX code>"
```

The difference is the usual with quotes in a shell command line: the former does no interpretation to the passed tokens, the latter will expand tokens in the standard way (for instance environment variables); in this case, backslashes for TeX code should be doubled, which is not necessary for the first option with single quotes.

Here `<program name>` stands for any binary corresponding to a TeX engine (`pdftex`, `xetex`, `luatex` and others) or a symbolic link to it (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex` and others), when a format named as the symlink will be loaded first; otherwise the format built upon `plain.tex` will be used.

A feature of all engines is that the job name is set according to the first input file.

Thus, if you want to define a macro before starting the real job, you can call

```
xetex '\def\foo{whatever}\input filename'
```

and the job name will be set to `filename` just as if `xetex filename` had been called.

Note that this works so long as the first character after the quote is a backslash: another character would trigger the lookup for a filename to be directly input. In case you want to typeset a banner, start with `\relax`: so

```
xetex '\relax abcdef\par\input filename'
```

will typeset a paragraph before inputting the file.

You could even input a different file, maintaining the desired job name:

```
xetex -jobname=filename '\input xyz\input filename'
```

will ignore the fact that `xyz.tex` is the first input file for the purpose of setting the job name.